# Using member variable as predicate

Tags: c++

I am trying to find an object in a vector of objects whos value of a member variable is true. Could it be done without defining a lamba function or function object, by just specifying the member variable itself:

```
class A
{
public:

   explicit A(bool v, int v2, float v3) : value(v), value2(v2), value3(v3)
   {}
   ...
   bool value;
   int value2;
   float value2;
   ...
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.push_back(A(false, 1, 1.0));
    v.push_back(A(true, 2, 2.0));
    v.push_back(A(false, 3, 3.0));

    auto iter = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), &A::value);
}
```

Compiling as is above does not work as it assumes a A* and not A.

Not that its a problem to use lambdas, just curious.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @juanchopanza Didnt compile, requires A* as input is you use &A::value, and not A which is passed byt find_if

Comment: Define an equality comparison operator for the class, that compares an instance of the class and a boolean value, and simply use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)? You can't really get around the need to write some code to compare values.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, The actual object is more complex so using the == operator would not work. This should be made more clear in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `std::mem_fn`

```
auto iter = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fn(&A::value));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f0b970471145e48)

Note that [range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) should allow directly:

```
auto iter = range::find_if(v, &A::value);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use C++11 lambdas, you can do that with `std::bind`:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(&A::value, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be the following

1. (Optional) Don't mark your constructor `A(bool)` as explicit to allow implicit conversion from `bool` to `A` ([live demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c90e10aba6cc0996))
2. Overload `operator==()` so that it only uses `value` to establish equality.

You can also supply an `operator==(bool v) { return value == v;}` (see this [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d916357e79784b58))

Of course I would advise you not to use that solution as it is quite dirty. Just supply a predicate using `std::find_if` to do the job. Note that the said predicate must have an `operator()` so of course you cannot supply a value such as a `bool` as the predicate to `std::find_if`

Comment: My actual constructor is more complex, but otherwise a good approach

Comment: @thorsan then just make an overloaded equality operator taking a bool argument as I suggested later on my answer. Though I find Jarod and Maxim answers much better