# What is the minimal way to write a free function to get the member of a class?

Tags: c++, generics, getter, perfect-forwarding, non-member-functions

(This question popped to my mind after reading [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74335759/how-do-i-use-member-functions-to-a-standard-library-ranges-operation) and [its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74335815/5825294).)

Assume a class `Foo` that you cannot modify, that has a `public` member `bar`, but no getter for it.

You might want to write a function to get that memeber when passed a `Foo`, so that you can use it in higher order functions, such as `std::transform` and similar.

In other words, given a class like this

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int bar{};
    ~Foo() { bar = -1; } // on most compilers this helps "verifying" that the object is dead
};
```

I would like some `getFoo` such that `getBar(expr-of-type-Foo)` has the same semantics as `expr-of-type-Foo.bar`, where *`expr-of-type-Foo`* is any object of type `Foo`, which can be a prvalue, an xvalue, or an lvalue.

How do you write it?

What I initially came up with is:

```cpp
        constexpr auto getBar = overload(
            [](auto& foo) -> decltype(auto) { return (foo.bar); },
            [](auto const& foo) -> decltype(auto) { return (foo.bar); },
            [](auto&& foo) -> auto { return foo.bar; }
        );
```

(`-> auto` is redundant, but I think it's informative in this context.)

My reasoning was as follows.

I need this `getBar` to behave differently for the different value categories, so it's a good idea to write it as an overload set; for this purpose I'm using [`boost::hana::overload`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga83e71bae315e299f9f5f9de77b012139).

However I'm not sure the solution I found it's minimal (assuming it is sufficient).

For instance,

- Given one of the overloads given I've overloaded on `auto&`/`auto const&`/`auto&&`, the latter will only catch rvalues, so in the other two cases I know I want to return a reference, so I could return `-> auto&` and `-> auto const&` instead of `decltype(auto)` and even remove the parenthesis from the `return`ed expression:

  ```cpp
      constexpr auto getBar = overload(
          [](auto& foo) -> auto& { return foo.bar; },
          [](auto const& foo) -> auto const& { return foo.bar; },
          [](auto&& foo) -> auto { return foo.bar; }
      );
  ```
- At this, point, though, I don't think I need two overloads `(auto&) -> auto&`/`(auto const&) -> auto const&`, because the former will naturally resolve to the latter when fed with a `const` expression, so I think I could go for this:

  ```cpp
      constexpr auto getBar = overload(
          [](auto& foo) -> auto& { return foo.bar; },
          [](auto&& foo) -> auto { return foo.bar; }
      );
  ```

But I don't see a way to simplify it further, at the moment.

[Here are my attempts to test it](https://godbolt.org/z/1Pr17Gr6x):

```cpp
#include<assert.h>
#include<boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp>

struct Foo {
    int bar{};
    ~Foo() {
        bar = -1;
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        constexpr auto getBar = overload(
            [](auto&& foo) -> auto { return foo.bar; },
            [](auto& foo) -> auto& { return foo.bar; }
        );
        {
            Foo foo{3};
            assert(&getBar(foo) == &foo.bar);
            assert(getBar(foo) == 3);

            foo.bar = 4;
            assert(foo.bar == 4);
            assert(getBar(foo) == 4);

            getBar(foo) = 5;
            assert(foo.bar == 5);
            assert(getBar(foo) == 5);
        }
        {
            Foo const foo{3};
            assert(&getBar(foo) == &foo.bar);
            assert(getBar(foo) == 3);

            //foo.bar = 3;     // Expectedly fails to compile.
            //getBar(foo) = 3; // Expectedly fails to compile.
        }
        {
            auto const& foobar = getBar(Foo{3});
            assert(foobar == 3);
            //foobar = 5; // Expectedly fails to compile.
        }
        {
            //auto& foobar = getBar(Foo{3}); // Expectedly fails to compile.
            //auto& foobar = Foo{3}.bar;     // Expectedly fails to compile.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `#define getBar(foo) (foo).bar`?

Comment: Ahah, I expected a comment from [you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811783/5825294). Anyway, yes, the macro is easy, but doesn't seem to be necessary, in this case, no? I know it is necessary [in other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74335759/how-do-i-use-member-functions-to-a-standard-library-ranges-operation). I was thinking of using a macro to _make_ a `getWhatever` function.

Comment: Ah, missed you were passing this on as a function somehow.  Yeah, the macro wont help with that.  I think what you have might be the shortest bit of code to get what you want.

Comment: Slightly simpler without using `overload` would just be standalone functions: `auto& getBar(Foo &f) { return f.bar; }` and/or `const auto& getBar(const Foo &f) { return f.bar; }`, depending on your needs.  Or maybe even a single function `template <typename T> auto& getBar(T &&t) { return t.bar; }` that uses a [*forwarding reference*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) to handle different types of reference inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for minimal work:

```cpp
const auto getBar = std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar);
```

This particular use case appears to do what you want.  In C++20, it was upgraded to be `constexpr`, but that might or might not be available.  Unlike the other question, which has overloadable member functions, a member variable isn't ambiguous.  So I would fall back to the above.